# How to properly display a result graph in flutter

Tags: flutter, graph, flutter-layout, flutter-packages

I am building an app with flutter where people test a trait of their personality and in the end get a result for this trait, ranging between -1 and +1.

Now I have looked at a few designs for displaying results, but all the packages and addons I find are more about bar or line charts, which doesnt really help me. I am also fairly new to flutter and have no idea how to display a graph like I imagine it (eg. how do I tell flutter to move the point left and right depending on the score)

[image]

Does anybody know a package that could help me here for a design like this? Or if you dont know it, could you quickly explain to me how I move the markers left and right dependig on the score?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flutter's inbuilt range slider

Doc link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RangeSlider-class.html

To make it as fancy as possible check out [Fusion's Sliders](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_sliders)
Also [Flutter xliders](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider)